# How to call Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript From foreach for each iteration

Tags: c#-4.0

How to call Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript from foreach for each iteration. It looks like it call all iterations once at end

```
 int  saveImageCount=0;

 foreach (DataRow Stdrow in key.ColumnValues)
{
    saveImageCount++
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SaveImage" + saveImageCount, "javascript:SaveImage();", true);
}
```

Unable to call javascript:SaveImage for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

They will all have the same type, so they'll override each other until the last one, and the last one will "win".

Instead build up a string and then, outside of the foreach, register the string.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan,I think you are a little bit mislead,its Type and key that makes unique combination not only type.
So @brijesh is 95% right but he has to use Register.ClientScriptBlock as it will be registered based on event not on page load.

```
 int saveImageCount = 0;
 foreach (DataRow Stdrow in key.ColumnValues)
  {
   saveImageCount++;
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script"+saveImageCount, "alert('data has been added successfully');", true);  
  }
```

GetType and "script"+saveImageCount will make a unique key combination and hence your script will be called without hesitation.